# Create channel between 2 peers in the same organization in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In HyperLedger Fabric is it possible to create a channel between peers that belong to the same organization / MSP? If so, how can this be configured in crypto-config.yaml and configtx.yaml?

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a single organization in the configtx.yaml

However, you have to include some orderer in the channel too. 
The orderer can also be in the same organization as the peers.